# Does factory resetting a phone erase spyware?

Tags: phone, spyware

I thought that there was spyware on my phone so I did a factory reset.

Would the spyware be gone or it will still exist even after a factory reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances of malware surviving a factory reset are very, very small, but not zero.

If you have rooted your phone, there is a small chance that malware can copy itself to the `system` partition, so it would survive a factory reset. Some anti-theft software will do the same for legit reasons: if a thief steals a phone and performs a factory reset, the owner can still track the phone.

If you are resetting the phone, you can do a *firmware upgrade*: download the latest firmware package from the phone manufacturer, and follow the instructions to upgrade the firmware. This will wipe out any trace of anything on the phone.

Comment: I have not rooted my phone then can it survive?

Comment: @10E_13_Bipin I believe this question has been answer by ThoriumBR. Please read again his answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely gone. Very hard to persist after a factory reset.
If you rooted your phone, chances are that the malware "fakes" the factory reset but that seems pretty advanced.

It could get reinstalled if you resync an account which automatically installs certain apps.

How do you know there is spyware on the device?

Comment: I dont know i used a public wifi thatswhy i was insecured

Comment: Using a public wifi does not mean you got spyware. You usually get spyware by installing apps outside of Play Store, and on rare cases, installing some from the Play Store...

Comment: Probably nothing to worry about in your case. Tons of people use insecure WiFi. It is possible that someone saw some unencrypted traffic but installing spyware is pretty unlikely. Even most important apps do not use unencrypted traffic anymore. There are exceptions ofcourse.

Comment: I didnt installed any apk i just browsed internet and saw some videos online!